# Stream, Map, Reduce... how is it done?

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get my head into Java 8 streams and still get stuck every now and then. I currently have a problem that I know it can be done with streams, I just can't seem to understand how to use them properly.

I have a list of Strings A and try to find all elements a of A that match another element b of A by a certain rule, then create a `Map<String, List<String>>` out of it with all a's -> all matched b's.

In detail:

- For each a in A, compare to each b in A using predicate P.
- If P(a,b) matches, generate a pair (x, y) from a and b.
- Group all pairs by x and return as a map.

Can you please give me a working Java 8 stream example for this?

**Edit:** How I would do it in an unnecessary expensive way:

```
Pairs(x,y) = forEach(a,b in A) 
  where (a != b && P(a, b)) 
  generatePairXY(a, b)
Map(x -> List(y)) = group(Pairs(x,y)) by x
```

Problem in this approach is that I first need to construct a huge list of pairs, which - given my data-set of a few million words - could exhaust memory.

Comment: You are basically creating equivalence groups. Your approach will result in an N-fold duplication of each group, where N is the group size. If you could instead define a *discriminator function*, which produces a unique value for each group, then the complexity of your algorithm would be significantly reduced.

Comment: I'd love to see a working code example for your idea.

Comment: With the discriminator function defined, it would be a simple `collect(groupingBy(discriminatorFn))` operation. The definition of the function is up to you, of course.

Comment: I am still having difficulties understanding all these higher-level stream functions, that's why I asked this question. My mind sadly just works by example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<String> list = ...;
Map<String, List<String>> map = 
  list.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a, a -> list.stream()
                                                 .filter(b -> P(a,b))
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList()))
               );
```

The idea is to create a map with a key for each String of the original list, and a value which is a filtered list of all the Strings matching that key.

EDIT :

Here's a full working example, in which the predicate P returns true if the two Strings are not equal but have the same length :

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test
{

  public static boolean P (String a, String b)
  {
    return a.length() == b.length() && !a.equals(b);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add ("aaa");
    list.add ("bbb");
    list.add ("ccc");
    list.add ("cccc");
    list.add ("dddd");
    list.add ("ddd");

    Map<String, List<String>> map = 
      list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a, a -> list.stream()
                                                     .filter(b -> P(a,b))
                                                     .collect(Collectors.toList()))
               );
    for (String key : map.keySet ()) {
      System.out.print (key + ": " );
      for (String value : map.get(key)) {
        System.out.print (value+ " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }

}
```

Output :

```
aaa: bbb ccc ddd
ccc: aaa bbb ddd
bbb: aaa ccc ddd
ddd: aaa bbb ccc
dddd: cccc
cccc: dddd
```

Comment: Problem is that `a` from the first parameter cannot be used as variable in the second parameter `P(a, b)`

Comment: @TwoThe I fixed and tested the code. Please see the included working example.